# Why HTML tags are replaced by '+AD-'?

Tags: notepad++

I have an HTML file that looks proper, but when I run a find and replace on it, I get the file changes to the following. I tried resaving the file through windows notepad and setting the Encoding, but i still get these weird characters.

Before:

```
<TABLE width='100%' border='0' bgcolor='#6699cc' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' ...
```

After:

```
+ADw-TABLE width+AD0-'100+ACU-' border+AD0-'0' bgcolor+AD0-'+ACM-6699cc' cellspacing+AD0-'0' cellpadding+AD0-'0' ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Encoding correctly.

That appears to be [UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7).

> UTF-7 is used by less than 0.003% of websites.[1] UTF-8 has since 2009 been the dominant encoding (of any kind, not just of Unicode encodings) for the World Wide Web (and declared mandatory "for all things" by WHATWG[2]).

Comment: You were right, I didn't convert all files to UTF-8. Appreciate it.